# How to highligth the active link in menu with gulp-file-include?

Tags: gulp

I use the gulp to build my project. I have multipage web-site. How I can highligth the active link in menu with gulp-file-include plugin while building?

Otherwise I need to change active CSS class on each page in build version.

[gulp-file-include](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include)